# Como criar um heatmap para um calendário?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Um dos gráficos que considero mais interessantes é chamado, em inglês, de *heatmap calendar*. Talvez sua aplicação mais comum seja no [github](https://github.com/mnunes/), que exibe nossas colaborações no último ano com o gráfico abaixo:

[image: Heatmap calendar no github]

Como é possível criar uma visualização como essa no R? Abaixo disponibilizo os valores do índice Bovespa nos últimos 5 anos para quem quiser contribuir com uma resposta.

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)

bvsp <- BatchGetSymbols('^BVSP', 
                        first.date = as.Date("2015-01-01"), 
                        last.date = as.Date("2019-12-31"))
```

Comment: Talvez o pacote `devtools::install_github("jayjacobs/ggcal")` possa ajudar. Ou este post do [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/calendar-heatmaps-in-ggplot/).

Comment: O nome deste tipo de gráfico "waffle chart" ou gráfico de pizza quadrado. Não vou conseguir responder rápido, mas esses projetos devem ajudar: [hrbrmstr/waffle](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle) e [liamgilbey/ggwaffle](https://github.com/liamgilbey/ggwaffle/)

Comment: O "desafio" do caso vai ser transformar expandir os dados para os 365 dias do ano e depois montar o gráfico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O pacote [ggTimeSeries](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggTimeSeries/index.html) tem a função `ggplot_calendar_heatmap` para isso:

```
library(ggTimeSeries)

dados <- data.frame(
  data = seq(as.Date("1/01/2019", "%d/%m/%Y"), as.Date("31/12/2019", "%d/%m/%Y"), "days"),
  valor = sample(1:5, 730, replace = TRUE))

ggplot_calendar_heatmap(dados, "data", "valor",
                        dayBorderSize = .5, dayBorderColour = "gray",
                        monthBorderSize = .5) +
  scale_fill_gradient(NULL,
                      low = "lightyellow", high = "darkgreen",
                      guide = "legend") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(NULL)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]